No prompt coming on fileHandle.requestPermission() inside chrome extension
I have scoured StackOverFlow but still could not make any sense of this issue.
The error that I am getting is:
DOMException: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.
But I am not receiving any request to allow/deny on the website page.
Here's the code:
async function verifyPermission(fileHandle, readWrite) {
    const options = {};
    if (readWrite) {
      options.mode = 'readwrite';
    }
    if ((await fileHandle.queryPermission(options)) === 'granted') {
      return true;
    }
    if ((await fileHandle.requestPermission(options)) === 'granted') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

async function saveFile(t) {
    console.log("I entered saveFile now.")
    try {
        const [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker({
            types: [{
              description: 'Text Files',
              accept: {'text/plain': ['.txt']}
            }],
            multiple: false
          });
        const permitted = await verifyPermission(fileHandle, true);  
        const writableStream = await fileHandle.createWritable();
        if (permitted) {
            let file = fileHandle.getFile();
            let size = await file.size;
            console.log(size);
            await writableStream.seek(size);
        }
        await writableStream.write(t);
        await writableStream.close();
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    }
  }

And here's the manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
      }
    ],
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "scripting", "tabs"],
    "optional_permissions": ["fileSystemProvider", "fileBrowserHandler"]
  }

I tried reading the other threads on Stack Overflow, GitHub issues and Reddit. Especially the ones related to Notifications.
I changed the settings on my browser. I allowed 'notifications' and 'popups and redirects' on all sites.
I went through the permissions and optional_permissions in chrome API.

Sounds like a bug in Chrome, it probably can't show such prompts from the popup. Try doing it in the content script. OTOH there should be no need for requestPermissions if you just use showSaveFilePicker. Also no need for optional_permissions, those APIs are unrelated.
